# ng-animate not firing event (ng-enter)

Tags: angularjs

I have the following angularjs application which loads content from Instagram, however, on page load I would like to fade the loaded content in with a smooth transition.

For some reason ng-animate doesn't seem to be firing the ng-enter event. so I can add a CSS animation. Is there something wrong?

**HTML**

```
 <section ng-controller="ShowImages as images" class="page {{ loadedClass }}" >
     <div ng-view>
      ......
     </div>
```

**JS**

```
(function(){
  //Place your own Instagram client_id below. Go to https://instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/ and register your app to get a client ID
  var client_id = '83aaab0bddea42adb694b689ad169fb1';
  //To get your user ID go to http://jelled.com/instagram/lookup-user-id and enter your Instagram user name to get your user ID
  var user_id = '179735937';

  var app = angular.module('instafeed', ['ngAnimate']);
  app.filter('getFirstCommentFrom',function(){
  return function(arr, user){
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
      if(arr[i].from.username==user)
        return arr[i].text;
    }
    return '';
  }
})

  app.factory("InstagramAPI", ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
      fetchPhotos: function(callback){
        var endpoint = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/liked/";
        endpoint += "?access_token=179735937.83aaab0.e44fe9abccb5415290bfc0765edd45ad";
        endpoint += "&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";

        $http.jsonp(endpoint).success(function(response){
          callback(response.data);

        });
      }
    }
  }]);

  app.controller('ShowImages', function($scope, InstagramAPI){
      $scope.layout = 'grid';
      $scope.data = {};
      $scope.pics = [];

      $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
          $scope.loadedClass = 'page-feed';
      });

      InstagramAPI.fetchPhotos(function(data){
          $scope.pics = data;
          console.log(data)
      });
  });

})();
```

I also link to these in the HTML:

```
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

See here:
http://machinas.com/wip/machinas/instagramfeed/

Comment: What exactly are you trying to animate? The page load or the images loading in? Also, how are you certain ng-enter is not firing?

Comment: just the page load and I'm certain because I have a class in the css, you can also see in firebug

Comment: Highly doubt that as it's built in, maybe double check your css and linking to animate?

Answer (score 0):

Do u ve included the css file right??
I think u don't need this:

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
          $scope.loadedClass = 'page-feed';
  });
```

The ng-enter is active when u set the value of the var that u use inside the ng-repeat

look at this http://codepen.io/shprink/pen/Ariyc